# Recovering control of a closed input descriptor process

Tags: scheme, file-descriptor, io-redirection

Doing some tests in scm (a scheme interpreter), I've intentionally closed the current-input-port (equivalent to the standard input file descriptor). Once the program work in REPL, the things got crazy, printing systematically a error message. My question is: how could I recover the control of process, that means, how could I reestablish the input file descriptor of such process?

Search for "changing file descriptor of a running process" or something similar, I couldn't find a helpful article.

Thanks in advance

System information: Debian 10.

Comment: Why did you close `current-input-port`? It's not something that you would normally do.

Comment: If I've got what you mean, the best way to resolve this would be avoid such situation apparently senseless, right?

I'm agree it's not something usual. But this is not the point. The point is how to recover the control over the process (i.e., not killing it and open it again).

Comment: You usually can't re-open the standard input of a process – there is certainly no cross-platform solution. (And the point *is* that your closing `current-input-port` is a bug that needs to be removed, not worked around.)

Comment: I'm not convinced that closing the current-input-port is necessary a bug independently of the situation. Anyway, your answer is relevant. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly can't, although this does slightly depend on how the language-level ports are mapped to the underlying OS-level I/O system.

If what you do is close the OS-level standard input then all is lost:

1. the REPL tries to read from standard input, gets an error as it's closed;
2. it tries to raise some error which will involve prompting the user for input ...
3. ... from standard input, which is closed, so it gets error;
4. game over.

The only way to survive this is for one of two things to be true:

- either you've wrapped an error handler around the code which is already prepared to deal with this;
- or the implementation is smart enough to recognise that it's getting closed-port errors in its closed-port error handler and gives up in some smart way.

Basically once the OS level standard input is gone anything that needs to get input from it is doomed: you can't put it back without OS-level surgery on the process.

However it's possible that the implementation maps a single OS-level I/O stream to multiple language-level streams, and closing only one of these streams would leave the system with some other stream-of-last-resort to which it can still talk, and which still refers to the OS-level standard input.  Common Lisp is an example of a system which can (depending on configuration) do this.  It has, for instance, `*standard-input*` `*error-output*`, `*query-io*`, `*terminal-io*` and other streams, and it's very possible to be in a situation where, for instance, `*standard-input*` has been closed causing read errors, but `*query-io*` still points somewhere with a human on the end of it.

I don't know if scm does that.

Comment: Finally something robust to think about. Thanks a lot!